# Confused about why this join isn't working - partition in PostgreSQL (dbVisualizer Pro)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, partition

```
with C_ID as (
select constituent_id
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',1) as C_ID_1
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',2) as C_ID_2
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',3) as C_ID_3
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',4) as C_ID_4
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',5) as C_ID_5
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',6) as C_ID_6
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',7) as C_ID_7
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',8) as C_ID_8
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',9) as C_ID_9
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',10) as C_ID_10
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',11) as C_ID_11
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',12) as C_ID_12
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',13) as C_ID_13
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',14) as C_ID_14
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',15) as C_ID_15
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',16) as C_ID_16
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',17) as C_ID_17
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',18) as C_ID_18
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',19) as C_ID_19
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',20) as C_ID_20
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',21) as C_ID_21
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',22) as C_ID_22
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',23) as C_ID_23
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',24) as C_ID_24
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',25) as C_ID_25
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',26) as C_ID_26
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',27) as C_ID_27
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',28) as C_ID_28
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',29) as C_ID_29
        , split_part (constituent_id, ',',30) as C_ID_30
        , item_id
from moma)
select *
from moma_artists
        left join c_id on moma_artists.constituent_id = c_id_2
where 1=1
        and c_id_2 is not null
order by moma_artists.constituent_id desc
limit 50
```

Can someone ID why this isn't working? There are items in C_ID_2 that should match moma_artists.constituent_ID but it's returning blank. Both fields in the database are varchar so it's not a mismatched column type.

What I'm really trying to do is practice "or" joins where I can join tables on multiple columns to return duplicate artists and be able to see all the works by each artist, regardless of whether they're a secondary or tertiary (or the thirtieth) artist. But I'm first trying to join on the C_ID_2 column and despite there clearly being data there it is just not joining.

[The dataset that I'm working with is in this spreadsheet in the tab "Problem Data"](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VUb723c_PmRSxdqCIAVqPUnu1B8Xr0A8bCuIFCvEDAg/edit?usp=sharing). This spreadsheet has the return of the partition and the join on C_ID_1, so part of my split definitely worked, just not anything past the first partition. The full database of artists I'm looking at is in there too, feel free to download anything you need. All the code in the "Code" tabs is clean and can be copy/pasted quickly.

Comment: can you please make a https://dbfiddle.uk/S9ZOHCkV  but contentid as linking should idnr4 when im counting right

Comment: Hi - please don’t link to external sites (though setting up and fiddle is ok) - all questions should be self-contained I.e. contain all relevant information as editable text. Also, just as an aside, no-one with even a basic understanding of security should be opening random file links from people they don’t know - so you linking to a spreadsheet doesn’t help anyone

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - unfortunately I am unable to put that amount of code in here. I don't appreciate the snark at the end of your comment. I'm just starting out. Rudeness is never necessary.